# What can we know if $f(x)\geq 0$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)<\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

Suppose that $f$ is differentiable function such that $f(x)\ge0$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)<\infty$. Which of the following statements must always be true?

I. $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0$

II.$\lim_{x\to \infty}f'(x)=0$

III. For every $\epsilon>0$, there is an $M$ such that $\int_{x>M}f(x)\, dx<\epsilon$

IV. $f$ is bounded

The answer is III., but I wonder if there's any example to show that I and II are not necessarily true. Thanks.

Comment: The particulars in your question differ from your title.

Comment: Fix you title.  Your title is impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For I and II, I won't give an explicit formula, but you can give a counterexample that covers both of them that has bumps of a constant maximum height, say $1$, that get less and less wide that will make both limits not exist, but the integral will still converge if the bumps shrink in width fast enough. The integral will not exist however if 
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) =L$$
for some $L\neq 0$.

As fleablood mentions in a comment, with the width shrinking fast enough we could also make the height of the bumps increase without bound, giving a counterexample to all three.

Comment: And as a counter example to IV the bumps can increase in linearly in size while the width decreases geometrically.

Comment: Hello, sir. I wonder you the function $f$ has countable discontinuities? If so, then is $f$ still be differentiable?

Comment: @Jie $f$ can still be differentiable. The bumps are not discontinuities, they increase to the maximum then decrease.

Answer (score 2):

To add form to Matt Samuels suggestion.

consider That on the interval $x\in (n- \frac 1{n\cdot2^n}, n + \frac 1{n\cdot 2^n})$ that $f(x) = n\cos (\frac {\pi}2\cdot\frac {x-n}{2\frac 1{n\cdot2^n}})$ and if $x$ is not in such an interval $f(x) = 0$.

That is:  That only on this intervals that are $\frac 2{n\cdot 2^n}$ wide the function has an adjusted cosine wave that goes from $0$ up to $n$ high[1] but is $0$ at all other points.  This has no discontinuities nor does its first derivative.

So $\int_0^{\infty} f(x) dx < \sum \frac {2}{n\cdot 2^n}n =\sum \frac 1{2^{n-1}} = 2$.[2]

But I,II,IV are all contradicted.

[1].

On the interval $[-\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2]$, $\cos x$ goes from $0$ to a height of $1$ ad $x = 0$ back down to  $0$.

On the interval $[n-1, n+1]$, $n*\cos (\frac \pi 2*(x-n))$ goes from $0$ to a height of $n$ at $x = n$ back down to $0$.

On the interval $[n-k, n+k]$, $n\cos (\frac \pi 2*\frac{x-n}{2k})$ goes from $0$ to a height of $n$ at $x = n$ back down to $0$.

So on the interval $[n- \frac 1{n\cdot2^n}, n + \frac 1{n\cdot 2^n}]$ then $f(x) = n\cos (\frac {\pi}2\cdot\frac {x-n}{2\frac 1{n\cdot2^n}})$ goes from $0$  to a height of $n$ at $x = n$ back down to $0$.

[2]

$\int_0^{\infty} f(x) dx = $

$\int_0^{\frac 12} f(x)dx + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} [\int_{n- \frac 1{n\cdot2^n}}^{n + \frac 1{n\cdot 2^n}}f(x)dx + \int_{n + \frac 1{n\cdot 2^n}}^{(n+1)} -\frac 1{(n+1)\cdot2^{n+1}}]=$

$0 +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} [\int_{n- \frac 1{n\cdot2^n}}^{n + \frac 1{n\cdot 2^n}}f(x)dx +0]=$

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{n- \frac 1{n\cdot2^n}}^{n + \frac 1{n\cdot 2^n}}f(x)dx<$

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(2\cdot\frac 1{n\cdot 2^n})n=$

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac 1{2^{n-1}} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac 1{2^0} = 2$.

Answer (score 1):

We can give an explicit formula with Samuel's idea. Had the integral (the bump)
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^{2}}{2 \sigma^{2}}} d x=1
$$
given, define $f$ as follow:
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{2^{4n}(x-n)^{2}}{2}}
$$, which in the $n$ term we take $\sigma=\frac{1}{2^{2n}}$ and $\mu=n$.
 The function $f$ does not satisfy i, ii, iv